# Universal Right UIBarButton for UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can i add universal right / left `UIBarButtonItem` to a `UINavigationController`? I am trying to make a navigation based app with same left and right navigation bar button for all `UIViewController`
Thank You

Comment: did u meant like a UITabBarController?? but on the right/left side??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a base UIViewController

```
@interface BaseController : UIViewController
{

}
@end


@implementation BaseController
- (id)init
{
    //set the universal barbuttonitem
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourView] autorelease];
}
@end
```

then all your viewController should extend from BaseController

that's done

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add the rightbarButtonItem in this way :-

UIBarButtonItem *btnName= [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc initWithTitle:@"btnTitle"   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btnAction)]autorelease];         
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnName;
```